# Refresh Token is not returned in @azure/msal-node using Authorization code flow?

Tags: azure, oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-msal

In example project provided by Microsoft [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/microsoftgraph/nodejs-webhooks-rest-sample/microsoft-graph-webhooks-sample-for-nodejs/) which uses Authorization code flow the acquireTokenByCode method does not return refresh tokens.

From @azure/msal-node here refresh token is not mentioned.

- Result returned from the authority's token endpoint.
- uniqueId               - `oid` or `sub` claim from ID token
- tenantId               - `tid` claim from ID token
- scopes                 - Scopes that are validated for the respective token
- account                - An account object representation of the currently signed-in user
- idToken                - Id token received as part of the response
- idTokenClaims          - MSAL-relevant ID token claims
- accessToken            - Access token received as part of the response
- fromCache              - Boolean denoting whether token came from cache
- expiresOn              - Javascript Date object representing relative expiration of access token
- extExpiresOn           - Javascript Date object representing extended relative expiration of access token in case of server outage
- state                  - Value passed in by user in request
- familyId               - Family ID identifier, usually only used for refresh tokens

Answer (score 0):

please ensure your MSAL authorization code request includes the *offline_access* scope.

Comment: `authContext.getAuthCodeUrl({
    redirectUri: msalConfiguration.redirectUri,
    scopes: ["offline_access", "User.Read" , "Mail.Read"]
  });`

Comment: I am adding offline_access scope even though I am not able to get refresh tokens. Also I have tried google oauth2.0 where I was able to get refresh tokens.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [MSAL.js](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js) to get token in this case, there is [`acquireTokenSilent`](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/blob/7cd420254b57b3a988446dc5774659a81a2bbd2a/lib/msal-browser/docs/acquire-token.md) method, it can perform silent renewal of tokens, which means you are no need to get the refresh token by yourself.

Popup

```
var request = {
    scopes: ["Mail.Read"]
};

msalInstance.acquireTokenSilent(request).then(tokenResponse => {
    // Do something with the tokenResponse
}).catch(async (error) => {
    if (error instanceof InteractionRequiredAuthError) {
        // fallback to interaction when silent call fails
        return myMSALObj.acquireTokenPopup(request);
    }
}).catch(error => {
    handleError(error);
});
```

Redirect

```
var request = {
    scopes: ["Mail.Read"]
};

msalInstance.acquireTokenSilent(request).then(tokenResponse => {
    // Do something with the tokenResponse
}).catch(error => {
    if (error instanceof InteractionRequiredAuthError) {
        // fallback to interaction when silent call fails
        return myMSALObj.acquireTokenRedirect(request)
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It's designed to *not* return the refresh token if you are using `@azure/msal-node`.
As they stated [in the discussion](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/issues/2836), the refresh token is handled background, inside the library itself for better *security*, which I also disagree with.

However, if you insist to have the token, you can manually call the API to the AzureAD endpoint.